# how to make a div background continuously move using animate in jquery

Tags: jquery

```
$("#marlin").animate({opacity:'0.4'});

   $("#marlin").animate({top:'550px',opacity:'0.4'},"slow");

    $("#marlin").animate({right:'430px'},"slow");

    $("#marlin").animate({top:'450px',opacity:'0.4'},"slow");

    $("#marlin").animate({top:'550px',opacity:'0.4'},"slow");

    $("#marlin").animate({right:'200px'},"slow");

    $("#marlin").animate({top:'350px',right:'210px',opacity:'0.4'},"slow");

    $("#marlin").animate({width:'50px',opacity:'0.4'},"slow");

   $("#marlin").animate({width:'50px',opacity:'0.6'},"slow");
```

Comment: I... don't even know what is going on here.

Comment: By using this code i amable to make it move from one place to another but unable to make it move constantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> you can go to this tutorial , 
> http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_animate.asp
> 
> hope it will help you.
```